# Directories created by boost::filesystem::create_directories() not immediately accessible?

Tags: synchronization, boost-filesystem, ext4, fsync, xfs

I am using [`boost::filesystem::create_directories()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#create_directories) to create new directories. When I try to access these directories shortly after creation, I get an error saying: no such directory. But if I sleep for a while after creating directories everything is fine (I do not get the error). Also, I tried using `fsync()` and `sync()` after creating directories but it made no difference. I am testing it on ext4 and xfs file systems and my boost version is boost 1.44

My questions are

1. Does `boost::create_directories()` create directories instantly? Or is it possible that something is wrong there?
2. Also, are `sync()` and `fsync()` guaranteed to flush everything to disc on ext4/xfs?